# Chrome extension: perform actions before page request is sent?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to perform actions before chrome sends a request to the server/webpage?

Does chrome throw a certain event my extension could catch and also block server connection if necessary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, its called webRequest api....
 https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest